# convert cordova wp silverlight to winrt

Tags: cordova, silverlight, windows-runtime

My team and I built a  windows phone app (Silverlight platform) with cordova (I think the cordova wp version is 3.8.1). Most of the JavaScript, html and css was taken from an already working android and ios based apps and Although it is a cordova based app, it uses some custom native code (espaecially notifications handling and location and about 10 custom plugins) writen in C#. We had a problem with some of the native features on the silverlight based app (especially the geofence feature), and microsoft engineers told us we shoud move to winrt. The problem is that in order of using the same app we have to change most of the already written code in the cordova version supporting winrt, some examples:  on the JavaScript side, 3rd party libraries function such as jquerymobile are not working properly and have to be changed to WinJS functions, on the plugins implementation side we have to re-implement the plugins with WinJS.
My questions are these :

1. Is there any tool giving a smooth conversion from a silverlight wp cordova app to  a winrt(or universal) wp cordova app? (This should probably be a embedded webview based app and not winJS).
2. If there is no alternative then what is the use of cordova at all in a winrt based app, since the js should be custom for wp, and I cant take an already working on ios and android webapp and make it work on wp (of course I have to implement the plugins...)

Answer (score 0):

If you update your app to an Windows 10 app (not Windows Phone 8.1), jquery mobile or any other framework they will work properly ;)

and no, there is unfortunately no tools :(